# Stop Div from Shrinking to Content in Fluid Layout

Tags: html, css, fluid

I have a centered div (#content) on my responsive site that resizes to the browser window, like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <p>Here is some sample text.</p>
  </div>
</div>

#container {
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  max-width: 805px;
}
```

It works, except for when the stuff inside `#content` doesn't take up enough horizontal space to push the div's width out to the max-width I have set. For example, instead of being 805px, one of my pages with little content between the paragraph tags is 740px.

I have tried adding `width: 100%` to `#content`, but that stops the div from resizing.

What's the best way to fix this? Do I need to use a media query?

Comment: Have you tried `min-width:805px;`?

Comment: That makes `#content` no longer responsive to the browser window size. It should start shrinking once the browser window gets too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I did need `width: 100%`, but I also needed `box-sizing: border-box`, and then I needed to include the added width of my padding into the `max-width`, like so:

```
#content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 885px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```